# MS Access to Sharepoint: One user gets '3073 Unupdateable Query'

Tags: microsoft-access

I have a couple MS Access 2010 tools that are frontends with SharePoint lists as the backend. They work fine for all users but one. When he clicks a button I made, it runs a couple queries to update SharePoint lists. One adds a record to a history list, and the other updates some fields in the main list. The main list update query cannot run and gives error 3073. He has access to the sharepoint lists and has made changes to the data successfully. If we run the same query from a different test form in the database then the update works ok.

The main form is a split form with a data source of the list that is being updated.  It is set to snapshot.  Setting the form's data source to a snapshot query of the list didn't help.  He is using interoperability Access (his version of Office does not have MS Access included), but so are other users and it works for them.

How can I get it so the last user can update the list data from the main form?

This question is replicated at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7aa60b40-ec7f-4c3d-8dac-9eac16213198/ms-access-to-sharepoint-one-user-gets-3073-unupdateable-query?forum=accessdev

Answer (score 0):

I made a temp table that I updated using VBA commands as the source for the main form instead of the list.  We were able to make updates then.  We also found the real problem:  The users were getting the front end with a script that loaded a local copy to their C drive and opened it.  For most users this is fine, but he had a screwy install of Access so the script was opening it in Interoperability mode instead of proper MS Access (which he actually did have).  When we opened Access first and opened the front end from there, then it worked as normal without needing a temp table.